Google Cloud Console Can't Connect
I am trying to use the google cloud console for a few months now but it never works.
The only way I can spin up google cloud instance is using the gui tools.
Is there any way to fix the "shell.cloud.google.com refused to connect."
It used to work a few years back. I had an instance running. I wanted to make software upgrades to my instance and after shutting it down it always says it's not available in that region. I made a new instance in the same region and it works. But I can't use more advanced tools that require CLI.
